# Subversion Edge (CSVNConsole) Not Accessible After Upgrading JAVA JRE to Version 8U371

Tags: java, svn, jre, jira

I upgraded JAVA JRE to v8u371 from v8u121 and confirmed both Subversion Edge and Subversion Server services are running. SVN commit completed successfully.

However, the CSVNConsole (https: on port 4434) is not accessible and resulted in "The connection has timed out" error.

Would anyone know of the root cause of this issue and how to resolve it?

Comment: Try changing the directory of the installation subdirectory from 121 to 371, there is absolutely o reason other than system environment variable, for a Java 8 upgrade to break something like Subversion. [Edit] your question instead of submitting a comment

Comment: The JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jre8.

Comment: The SVN console service is running, but the https link for the admin console failed to open. Would anyone know the difference between the cert and key on C:\csvn\data\certs vs. C:\csvn\data\conf folders?

Comment: It’s which ever folder contains the your certificate.